# How to add my isLoading constant to this conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

I added this constant

```
    const isLoading = !templates;
```

In order to Change the color of my button and prevent a click if my cards are still loading.

However, I dont know how to add my isLoading constant to this conditional statement.

```
<MenuButton
    className={
    !firstTimeOnOnboarding || selectedTemplatesIds.length >= minNumOfOptions
    ? `${styles.actionBlue}`: `${styles.actionNormal}`}>
    {buttonText}
</MenuButton>
```

I tried doing this but it doesnt work.

```
className={
!isLoading && !firstTimeOnOnboarding || selectedTemplatesIds.length >= minNumOfOptions ? `${styles.actionBlue}`: `${styles.actionNormal}`}
```

Comment: When adding a new condition to the ternary operator you need to wrap the "OR" conditions in brackets, but this depends on how you need the condition to work. 

I would assume you want to check !isLoading exclusively so you would need to wrap your existing condition like so: 


className={
!isLoading && (!firstTimeOnOnboarding || selectedTemplatesIds.length >= minNumOfOptions) ? `${styles.actionBlue}`: `${styles.actionNormal}`}

Comment: GREAT! WORKS! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want prevent click, what you do really need is disable button while Loading variable is true, as MenuButton is a custom component, you should create a prop "disabled" to manage button disabling.

This is an example with a HTML button tag. I added global class for the button to manage disabling and common attributes, if you want use more pretty option you can use "classnames package" for use multiples CSS classes

JSX:

```
<button
    className={
    !firstTimeOnOnboarding || selectedTemplatesIds.length >= minNumOfOptions
    ? `${styles.actionBlue} ${styles.myButton}`: `${styles.actionNormal} ${styles.myButton}`}
    disabled={isLoading}
>
    { isLoading ?  'Loading' : buttonText}
</button>
```

I added a CSS class because is a good practice show to user disabled button of visual way, and maybe you wonder how to do it.

CSS:

```
.actionBlue {
  ...your styles
}

.actionNormal {
  ...your styles
}

.myButton {
  ...if you want common styles, here
}

.myButton:disabled {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

Tips: I manage text my button while it is loading with this conditional.

```
 { isLoading ?  'Loading...' : buttonText}
```

Also I think, you should manage disibiling of your button with a "CSS Specificity".

```
.myButton {
  ...if you want common styles, here
}

.myButton.actionBlue {
  ...your styles
}

.myButton.actionNormal {
  ...your styles
}

.myButton:disabled {
  opacity: .5;
}
```